# Confusion over tensor products in sympy.physics.quantum.qubit (in Python)

Tags: programming, linear-algebra

I am working with `sympy.physics.quantum.qubit` to help teach myself more about quantum computing.

I'm confused about how best to simplify two ket expressions that appear to me to be identical.  Seems to me that `B` and `C` below should be the same:

```
B = Qubit('01')

C = TensorProduct(Qubit('0'),Qubit('1'))
```

because their representation is identical, i.e.

```
B.represent() == C.represent()       #returns True
```

it feels like they are the same qubit state.  So far, so good.

But now when I print out `B` and `C` I get:

```
print("B is", B)

B is |01>
```

but

```
print("C is", C)

C is |0>x|1>
```

### My question:

Is there some way I could get the Python library to use the output of `B` and `C` so that the equivalence between the two would be obvious?  Basically, how do I get `C` to simplify it's output so that it exactly resembles `B`?

Am grateful for any help you could provide.

Answer (score 2):

After some more reading of the documentation, I now realize the `C` above is a `TensorProduct` object (and not a `Qubit`) but `B` is a `Qubit`.   The way you can make the tensor product become a Qubit (and print it out in a way that's comparable with `B`) is to just call:

```
matrix_to_qubit(represent(C))
```

which returns a `Qubit` with the answer you'd expect.

Thanks for being patient with me as I worked that out.